# Handling image resource size on Android

Tags: android, android-resources, android-resolution

I am kind of confused about managing graphic resources in Android.
Tried to read [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but It only confuses me more. Can anyone give me some example of how should I handle the following case?

Lets assume that I have an image in my layout that will be scaled to fill screen width. What image sizes (in pixels) should I produce and what configuration qualifiers (drawable-{qualifier}) should I apply to those resources to cover all major dpi and screen sizes (both for tablet and handset)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an image, that is supposed to fill the screen it is best to use [9-patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch). This way your image can automatically scale to fit the device. Because even if an image has the correct density, the actual screen size can vary. For example a smartphone and a tablet can both be hdpi, but have completely different screen sizes (and actual pixel count).

So the easiest way to target most devices, when it comes to images that are supposed to fill up the full width of the screen is to have a 9-patch image and create ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi versions of it. This way the image will automatically be choosen depending on the density and then stretched to fit the device.

The android sdk also provides a tool that helps with creating 9-patch images http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html